# Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'ClassName'

Tags: swift

```
struct ColorPalette {
    var DefaultBarTintColor : UIColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x75b5d4)
    func UIColorFromRGB(rgbValue: UInt) -> UIColor {
        return UIColor(
            red: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0,
            green: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0x00FF00) >> 8) / 255.0,
            blue: CGFloat(rgbValue & 0x0000FF) / 255.0,
            alpha: CGFloat(1.0)
        )
    }
}
```

error : Cannot convert value of type "int' to expected argument type 'MyClassName'

If I do

```
view.backColor = UIColorFromRGB(UIColorFromRGB)
```

it works

But I want to do like this:

```
view.backColor = ColorPalette.DefaultBarTintColor
```

I don't know how to fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To call function inside `struct`, you need to use `static` keyword. Here is the modified function of your's!

```
struct ColorPalette {

static var DefaultBarTintColor : UIColor = ColorPalette.UIColorFromRGB(0x75b5d4)

static func UIColorFromRGB(rgbValue: UInt) -> UIColor {
    return UIColor(
        red: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0,
        green: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0x00FF00) >> 8) / 255.0,
        blue: CGFloat(rgbValue & 0x0000FF) / 255.0,
        alpha: CGFloat(1.0)
       )
   }
}
```

Now you can call like this!

```
view.backColor = ColorPalette.DefaultBarTintColor
```

Although, if you need to call without using the `static` keyword then you need to make the object of your `struct`. Like:

```
let myColorPallete = ColorPalette()
```

then you can access it like this:

```
viewNoEvents.backgroundColor = myColorPallete.DefaultBarTintColor
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of initializing property while declaration, you can have initializer function as below:

```
struct ColorPalette {
    var DefaultBarTintColor : UIColor!
    func UIColorFromRGB(rgbValue: Int) -> UIColor {
        return UIColor(
            red: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0,
            green: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0x00FF00) >> 8) / 255.0,
            blue: CGFloat(rgbValue & 0x0000FF) / 255.0,
            alpha: CGFloat(1.0)
        )
    }
    init(rgbValue: Int) {
        self.DefaultBarTintColor = UIColorFromRGB(rgbValue)
    }
}
```

And then create instance by passing hex value as below:

```
    var color = ColorPalette(rgbValue: 0x75B5D4)
```